# Upgrade Java 6 to Java 8

Tags: java, jboss

As per the project requirement, i need to upgrade my JDK1.6.0_45 to JDK1.8.

I am using JBOSS 4.2.3.GA, once i am pointing to JDK1.8 bin and trying to compile the project it is throwing the below error:
ERROR [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/web.ear/facade.jar
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build JAXB context

How can i fix this issue ?

Or any idea to migrate  from JDK1.6 to JDK1.8 ,what action i need to take ?

Comment: Do you just need to migrate the JDK Version? Then you could try to go with compatibility mode and run your JDK 1.8 with 1.6 compliance. Will not necessarily work fine, but I would give it a try.
If you also need to upgrade your code to 1.8 compliance... well, go ahead an plan a new project for that, this will be a time consuming task.

Comment: Could help: https://mahichir.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/running-jboss-4-2-3-ga-on-jdk-1-7-or-higher/

Comment: Thank you, i will try the steps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you're going to also need to upgrade to a newer JBoss. Everything up to JBoss AS 7 does not run on Java 8, so you'll need at least Wildfly 8.

Similarly, if you want Java 9 you'll need Wildfly 11.

Answer (score 0):

There will many other problems when you are migrating from 1.6 to 1.8, but this looks like You're using JAXB incompatible classes.

Please use the following maven dependency or switch to jaxb version 2.3.0

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It looks like after adding the Jaxb-Impl2.3.0  jar under JBoss endorsed folder lead the another error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader    , So will go through the JBoss upgrade as well to Wildfly 8 suggested by Jeroen Steenbeeke.